# Adobe Flash not being recognized on certain websites

Tags: firefox, flash

I have Adobe Flash Plugin v11.2r202 in Firefox 11.0, on Kubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

Flash works flawless on Youtube. However, certain websites claim that I need a more recent version of Flash Player. That is, of course, a wrong assumption. Because I have the latest version installed. Also, I tried Firefox add-on "flash aid". It didn't help.

For example, on this website:
http://htwins.net/scale2/
It says "You need a more recent version of Adobe Flash Player."

Whereas in Chromium or Opera, it works.

`about:plugins` contains this information about flash content:

```
Shockwave Flash
File: libflashplayer.so
Version: Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
MIME Type.....Description.....Suffixes
application/x-shockwave-flash.....Shockwave Flash.....swf
application/futuresplash.....FutureSplash Player.....spl
```

What is the problem there?

Comment: Please enter `about:plugins` into the address bar and list all your plugins that handle the `swf` extension with their file names and version numbers in your question. (Example: libflashplayer.so, Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. You seem to have the identical version as me and I could watch the page you suggested. The only difference I see is that you're on 64-bits whereas I'm on 32.

Answer (score 1):

Re-install flashplugin-installer. It worked for me